# Contract Call unrecognized-selector

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat

```
function initiateBet(uint256 amount) external {
    require(amount > 0, "Betrag muss groesser als 0 sein");
    //require(choice != BetOutcome.NotSet, "Ungueltige Wahl");

    // Transfer des Einsatzes von Spieler 1
    hardhatToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(owner), amount);

    // Wette erstellen
    bets[nextBetId] = Bet({
        player1: msg.sender,
        player2: address(0),
        amount: amount,
        player1Choice: BetOutcome.TeamA,
        player2Choice: BetOutcome.NotSet,
        isSettled: false
    });

    emit BetInitiated(msg.sender, nextBetId, amount);
    nextBetId++;
}
```

---

```
try {
    await this._peerToPeerBetting.initiateBet(amount);
    // Your remaining code
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
  }
```

---

```
  Contract call:       PeerToPeerBetting#<unrecognized-selector>
```

From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
To:                  0xe7f1725e7734ce288f8367e1bb143e90bb3f0512

---

When i have not enough tokens it seems to find the method
as soon as i have enough tokens it doesnt?

What am i doing wrong? Please Help!